# Snowflake sqlalchemy python cant connect because of getaddrinfo failed inside virtual machine of company network

Tags: sqlalchemy, proxy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, virtual-machine, database-engine

I need to read and write some data to a snowflake databse. I have the credentials and everything is working fine on my local pc. But in the virtual machine of the company I am doing this I get this
I think its a proxy problem but i dont know what to do and how to fix. On the virtual machine i can access the snowflake urls flawlessly and everything works in google chrome for example. but why is this request not working in python??
Why?
How can i fix it?
please help :(

```
error message `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
  File "socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002073B6C6C10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=d395ab35-5f2a-4fb2-a83b-48458979f2c9&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=19c8e3a5-33ad-48c2-8124-fc69a1fa2af9 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002073B6C6C10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\network.py", line 1018, in _request_exec
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\requests\adapters.py", line 565, in send
snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=d395ab35-5f2a-4fb2-a83b-48458979f2c9&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=19c8e3a5-33ad-48c2-8124-fc69a1fa2af9 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002073B6C6C10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 1072, in __authenticate
  File "snowflake\connector\auth.py", line 257, in authenticate
  File "snowflake\connector\network.py", line 704, in _post_request
  File "snowflake\connector\network.py", line 794, in fetch
  File "snowflake\connector\network.py", line 917, in _request_exec_wrapper
  File "snowflake\connector\network.py", line 837, in _request_exec_wrapper
  File "snowflake\connector\network.py", line 1095, in _request_exec
snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 251011: 251011: ConnectionTimeout occurred. Will be handled by authenticator

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 327, in connect
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 894, in _checkout
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 493, in checkout
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
  File "sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
  File "sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 273, in _create_connection
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 388, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 691, in __connect
  File "sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
  File "sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 686, in __connect
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 578, in connect
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 598, in connect
  File "snowflake\connector\__init__.py", line 51, in Connect
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 297, in __init__
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 550, in connect
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 789, in __open_connection
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 1052, in _authenticate
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 1117, in __authenticate
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 1094, in __authenticate
  File "snowflake\connector\auth_by_plugin.py", line 117, in handle_timeout
snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 250001: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\snowflakesqlalchemy.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3315, in connect
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 96, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3364, in _wrap_pool_connect
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2198, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
  File "sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 327, in connect
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 894, in _checkout
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 493, in checkout
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
  File "sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
  File "sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 273, in _create_connection
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 388, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 691, in __connect
  File "sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
  File "sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
  File "sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 686, in __connect
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 578, in connect
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 598, in connect
  File "snowflake\connector\__init__.py", line 51, in Connect
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 297, in __init__
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 550, in connect
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 789, in __open_connection
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 1052, in _authenticate
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 1117, in __authenticate
  File "snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 1094, in __authenticate
  File "snowflake\connector\auth_by_plugin.py", line 117, in handle_timeout
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError) 250001: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
[44952] Failed to execute script 'snowflakesqlalchemy' due to unhandled exception!`


I also printed these logs:
`2023-01-10 11:17:18,250 - MainThread connection.py:275 - __init__() - INFO - Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 2.8.3, Python Version: 3.9.13, Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
2023-01-10 11:17:18,250 - MainThread connection.py:520 - connect() - DEBUG - connect
2023-01-10 11:17:18,250 - MainThread connection.py:810 - __config() - DEBUG - __config
2023-01-10 11:17:18,250 - MainThread connection.py:934 - __config() - INFO - This connection is in OCSP Fail Open Mode. TLS Certificates would be checked for validity and revocation status. Any other Certificate Revocation related exceptions or OCSP Responder failures would be disregarded in favor of connectivity.
2023-01-10 11:17:18,251 - MainThread connection.py:952 - __config() - INFO - Setting use_openssl_only mode to False
2023-01-10 11:17:18,251 - MainThread converter.py:145 - __init__() - DEBUG - use_numpy: False
2023-01-10 11:17:18,251 - MainThread converter_issue23517.py:27 - __init__() - DEBUG - initialized
2023-01-10 11:17:18,251 - MainThread connection.py:713 - __open_connection() - DEBUG - REST API object was created: kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com:443
2023-01-10 11:17:18,252 - MainThread auth.py:170 - authenticate() - DEBUG - authenticate
2023-01-10 11:17:18,252 - MainThread auth.py:200 - authenticate() - DEBUG - assertion content: *********
2023-01-10 11:17:18,252 - MainThread auth.py:203 - authenticate() - DEBUG - account=kzhwbsi-gb82213, user=karlpd4c, database=project_database, schema=project_schema, warehouse=None, role=None, request_id=10256208-cea8-4269-a480-820a1c55e4a3
2023-01-10 11:17:18,252 - MainThread auth.py:236 - authenticate() - DEBUG - body['data']: {'CLIENT_APP_ID': 'PythonConnector', 'CLIENT_APP_VERSION': '2.8.3', 'SVN_REVISION': None, 'ACCOUNT_NAME': 'kzhwbsi-gb82213', 'LOGIN_NAME': 'karlpd4c', 'CLIENT_ENVIRONMENT': {'APPLICATION': 'PythonConnector', 'OS': 'Windows', 'OS_VERSION': 'Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0', 'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.9.13', 'PYTHON_RUNTIME': 'CPython', 'PYTHON_COMPILER': 'MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)', 'OCSP_MODE': 'FAIL_OPEN', 'TRACING': 10, 'LOGIN_TIMEOUT': 120, 'NETWORK_TIMEOUT': None}, 'SESSION_PARAMETERS': {'AUTOCOMMIT': False, 'CLIENT_PREFETCH_THREADS': 4}}
2023-01-10 11:17:18,252 - MainThread auth.py:254 - authenticate() - DEBUG - Timeout set to 120
2023-01-10 11:17:18,253 - MainThread retry.py:351 - from_int() - DEBUG - Converted retries value: 1 -> Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2023-01-10 11:17:18,253 - MainThread retry.py:351 - from_int() - DEBUG - Converted retries value: 1 -> Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2023-01-10 11:17:18,253 - MainThread network.py:1147 - _use_requests_session() - DEBUG - Session status for SessionPool 'kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', SessionPool 1/1 active sessions
2023-01-10 11:17:18,253 - MainThread network.py:827 - _request_exec_wrapper() - DEBUG - remaining request timeout: 120, retry cnt: 1
2023-01-10 11:17:18,254 - MainThread network.py:808 - add_request_guid() - DEBUG - Request guid: 3bcec6fe-8f7d-4c05-9203-626636c975ea
2023-01-10 11:17:18,254 - MainThread network.py:1006 - _request_exec() - DEBUG - socket timeout: 60
2023-01-10 11:17:18,257 - MainThread connectionpool.py:1003 - _new_conn() - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com:443
2023-01-10 11:17:19,295 - MainThread retry.py:594 - increment() - DEBUG - Incremented Retry for (url='/session/v1/login-request?request_id=10256208-cea8-4269-a480-820a1c55e4a3&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=3bcec6fe-8f7d-4c05-9203-626636c975ea'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2023-01-10 11:17:19,295 - MainThread connectionpool.py:812 - urlopen() - WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000299937F9A30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /session/v1/login-request?request_id=10256208-cea8-4269-a480-820a1c55e4a3&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=3bcec6fe-8f7d-4c05-9203-626636c975ea
2023-01-10 11:17:19,296 - MainThread connectionpool.py:1003 - _new_conn() - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (2): kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com:443
2023-01-10 11:17:19,297 - MainThread network.py:1090 - _request_exec() - DEBUG - Hit a timeout error while logging in. Will be handled by authenticator. Ignore the following. Error stack: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=10256208-cea8-4269-a480-820a1c55e4a3&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=3bcec6fe-8f7d-4c05-9203-626636c975ea (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000299937F9BE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
  File "socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000299937F9BE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=10256208-cea8-4269-a480-820a1c55e4a3&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=3bcec6fe-8f7d-4c05-9203-626636c975ea (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000299937F9BE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\network.py", line 1018, in _request_exec
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\requests\adapters.py", line 565, in send
snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=10256208-cea8-4269-a480-820a1c55e4a3&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=3bcec6fe-8f7d-4c05-9203-626636c975ea (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000299937F9BE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))
2023-01-10 11:17:19,305 - MainThread network.py:1152 - _use_requests_session() - DEBUG - Session status for SessionPool 'kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', SessionPool 0/1 active sessions
2023-01-10 11:17:19,305 - MainThread connection.py:1087 - __authenticate() - DEBUG - Operational Error raised at authenticationfor authenticator: AuthByDefault
2023-01-10 11:17:19,305 - MainThread auth_by_plugin.py:114 - handle_timeout() - DEBUG - Default timeout handler invoked for authenticator
2023-01-10 11:17:19,305 - MainThread auth_by_plugin.py:123 - handle_timeout() - DEBUG - Hit connection timeout, attempt number 0. Will retry in a bit...
2023-01-10 11:17:19,305 - MainThread auth_by_plugin.py:56 - next_sleep_duration() - DEBUG - Sleeping for 2 seconds
2023-01-10 11:17:21,306 - MainThread auth.py:170 - authenticate() - DEBUG - authenticate
2023-01-10 11:17:21,306 - MainThread auth.py:200 - authenticate() - DEBUG - assertion content: *********
2023-01-10 11:17:21,306 - MainThread auth.py:203 - authenticate() - DEBUG - account=kzhwbsi-gb82213, user=karlpd4c, database=project_database, schema=project_schema, warehouse=None, role=None, request_id=f8210470-5260-46c4-b7a5-1458f5dc318a
2023-01-10 11:17:21,306 - MainThread auth.py:236 - authenticate() - DEBUG - body['data']: {'CLIENT_APP_ID': 'PythonConnector', 'CLIENT_APP_VERSION': '2.8.3', 'SVN_REVISION': None, 'ACCOUNT_NAME': 'kzhwbsi-gb82213', 'LOGIN_NAME': 'karlpd4c', 'CLIENT_ENVIRONMENT': {'APPLICATION': 'PythonConnector', 'OS': 'Windows', 'OS_VERSION': 'Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0', 'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.9.13', 'PYTHON_RUNTIME': 'CPython', 'PYTHON_COMPILER': 'MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)', 'OCSP_MODE': 'FAIL_OPEN', 'TRACING': 10, 'LOGIN_TIMEOUT': 120, 'NETWORK_TIMEOUT': None}, 'SESSION_PARAMETERS': {'AUTOCOMMIT': False, 'CLIENT_PREFETCH_THREADS': 4}}
2023-01-10 11:17:21,307 - MainThread auth.py:254 - authenticate() - DEBUG - Timeout set to 120
2023-01-10 11:17:21,307 - MainThread network.py:1147 - _use_requests_session() - DEBUG - Session status for SessionPool 'kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', SessionPool 1/1 active sessions
2023-01-10 11:17:21,307 - MainThread network.py:827 - _request_exec_wrapper() - DEBUG - remaining request timeout: 120, retry cnt: 1
2023-01-10 11:17:21,307 - MainThread network.py:808 - add_request_guid() - DEBUG - Request guid: dbe010e1-6776-46ed-bc5a-9979d617bee4
2023-01-10 11:17:21,307 - MainThread network.py:1006 - _request_exec() - DEBUG - socket timeout: 60
2023-01-10 11:17:21,311 - MainThread connectionpool.py:1003 - _new_conn() - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (3): kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com:443
2023-01-10 11:17:21,312 - MainThread retry.py:594 - increment() - DEBUG - Incremented Retry for (url='/session/v1/login-request?request_id=f8210470-5260-46c4-b7a5-1458f5dc318a&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=dbe010e1-6776-46ed-bc5a-9979d617bee4'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2023-01-10 11:17:21,312 - MainThread connectionpool.py:812 - urlopen() - WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002999382B790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /session/v1/login-request?request_id=f8210470-5260-46c4-b7a5-1458f5dc318a&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=dbe010e1-6776-46ed-bc5a-9979d617bee4
2023-01-10 11:17:21,312 - MainThread connectionpool.py:1003 - _new_conn() - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (4): kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com:443
2023-01-10 11:17:21,314 - MainThread network.py:1090 - _request_exec() - DEBUG - Hit a timeout error while logging in. Will be handled by authenticator. Ignore the following. Error stack: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=f8210470-5260-46c4-b7a5-1458f5dc318a&databaseName=project_database&schemaName=project_schema&request_guid=dbe010e1-6776-46ed-bc5a-9979d617bee4 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002999382BA00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
  File "snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
  File "socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...
```

This is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import logging
import os
engine = create_engine('snowflake://user:password@myaccount(e.g.asdfhjk-jh45567)/project_database/project_schema')
os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = 'snowflakecomputing.com'
path = input('logpath:\n')
for logger_name in ['snowflake','botocore']:
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.FileHandler(path+'python_connector.log')
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(funcName)s() - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(ch)
try:
    
    connection = engine.connect()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM project_comments"
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql,connection)
    print(df)
    df.to_csv("./snowflakedata.csv",index=False)
finally:

    engine.dispose()
connection.close()
```

Besides working with sqlalchemy i tried the snowflake connector:

```
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector
import sys
import os
us = input("user: \n")
pw = input("password: \n")
acc = input("account: \n")
cnn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=us,
    password=pw,
    account=acc,
    
)
cs = cnn.cursor()
wh = input("warehouse: \n")
db = input("database: \n")
schema = input("schema: \n")
table = input("table: \n")
path = input("output directory: \n").replace("\\", "/")
try:
    sql = "USE WAREHOUSE " + wh
    cs.execute(sql)
    sql = "USE DATABASE "+ db
    cs.execute(sql)
    sql = "USE SCHEMA " + schema
    cs.execute(sql)
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql,cnn)
    print(df)
    df.to_csv(path + "snowflakedata.csv",index=False)
    input("snowflake has been read, press any key to close")
finally:
    cs.close()
cnn.close()
```

same problem occurs. On local pc its working fine and on the virtual machine in the on premise network it does not work.
and i tried to deactivate proxy in windows with:

```
set NO_PROXY=snowflakecomputing.com
```

Do I need the ip of the snowflake db? How do I get it? Is there something wrong with the dns configuration in sqlalchemy? how do i fix it? do i need another connector or database engine?

Comment: Execute the following command in a worksheet ```select system$allowlist()``` it will print a list of the URLs, then try setting no_proxy for all of them.

Comment: how do i set no proxy for them? 
is the command in windows console where the python script gets executed:
```set NO_PROXY=snowflakecomputing.com``` right?

Comment: for example how do i set for this entry:
```{"type":"SNOWFLAKE_DEPLOYMENT_REGIONLESS","host":"abcdef-ab12345.snowflakecomputing.com","port":443},```

Comment: my comment just to point out that if you have a proxy, or any sort of a firewall restricting the access to certain URLs, you should configure it not only for snowflakecomputing.com but for all urls associated with your snowflake account. How you do that depends on the network configuration in your case, which is unknown to us

Comment: ok but why can i access the urls via the browser, e.g. chrome or edge?

Comment: **getaddrinfo failed** means that Snowflake hostname cannot be resolved. You could reproduce this directly in Python shell by doing: **python -c "import socket; socket.getaddrinfo('kzhwbsi-gb82213.snowflakecomputing.com', 443)"**. The browser might work since you can set a proxy in Windows via calling a script, which won't work in Python.  Does your Windows has set a proxy at all ?

Comment: As I am working on a cooperate citrix virtual machine windows i am convinced it is behind a cooperate proxy. But i dont know how i can see if it is set on windows level or in browser? How do i check?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer:
If you are behind a coorperate proxy, you need to configure the proxy one in the environment variables as new variable then add these two:

HTTP_PROXY
http://companyuser:companypw@proxy.companydomain.companyname.com:8080
and

HTTPS_PROXY
http://companyuser:companypw@proxy.companydomain.companyname.com:8080

.Then you also need to configre those http and https proxy at application level, meaning in your python program at the beginning:

```
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://companyuser:companypw@proxy.companydomain.companyname.com:8080"
os.environ["https_proxy"] ="http://companyuser:companypw@proxy.companydomain.companyname.com:8080"
```

in my case the companyuser is the user from my windows machine.